# Tips for cleaning up a challenge's answer? Weighted Sum of Digits

Tags: python, sum, digits, weighted

I've been going through some code challenges. And one struck me in particular. CodeAbbey has a Weighted Sum of Digits challenge. And this was my answer.

```
# open and read a file, hardcoded numbers, etc. Here is a sample
raw_data = (6, 19, 64, 6527226, 12345146)  

for number in raw_data:
    wsd = 0  # Stores sum
    number_list = list(str(number))  # Converts the number into a list.
    for i, k in enumerate(number_list):  # Enumerates each number
        wsd += (int(i+1) * int(k))  # Multiplies and adds product to wsd
    print(wsd)

output >>> 6, 19, 14, 114, 137
```

Anyone with more experience able to see a better way of getting the sum?

Comment: If you are looking for code review, you might want to take it to the [code review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

If using map:

```
>>> map(lambda d: sum([ (i+1) * int(v) for i,v in enumerate(list(str(d)))]), raw_data)
[6, 19, 14, 114, 137]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for number in raw_data:
    print(sum(i * int(d) for i, d in enumerate(str(number), 1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done entirely using math operations. Look how the sum is generated, e.g. for 12345146:

```
                6
              4+6
            1+4+6
          5+1+4+6
        4+5+1+4+6
      3+4+5+1+4+6
    2+3+4+5+1+4+6
+ 1+2+3+4+5+1+4+6
```

So firs you add last digit, then last and previous, then last, previous and previous etc. until you add all digits. And this can be simply implemented by following algorithm:

```
raw_data = (6, 19, 64, 6527226, 12345146)  
for d in raw_data:
    wsd = 0
    lst = 0 # this is for holding last 'sum row'
    while d > 0:
        lst = lst + d % 10 # append another digit
        wsd += lst
        d //= 10
    #
    print wsd
#
```

On my computer this is about two times faster than algorithms using enumeration and string conversion (I multiplied raw_data 100000 times, thus getting 500000 elements for comparison).

Comment: did you check your output???

Comment: @MaxU: Yes, it gives 6, 19, 14, 114, 137

Comment: it gives me: 2165.9259259259325, 3608.76543209879, 3614.3209876543456, 10922.962962953508, 9480.123456823116 (in Python 3.5.1)

Comment: got it, you should replace: d /= 10 with d //= 10

Comment: @MaxU: I use python 2.7.3.

Comment: @MaxU: Thank you, code fixed.