# Weighted sum of digits in R

Tags: r, string

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to calculate the weighted sum of digits for a numeric string (where the weight is equal to the position of the digit in the numeric string).

Example: For the number 1059, the weighted sum of digits is calculated as `1 * 1 + 0 * 2 + 5 * 3 + 9 * 4 = 52`

I would like to allow for the input to be of any length, but if there are more efficient ways when there is a limit to the string length (e.g. knowing that the number is no more 10 digits allows for a more efficient program) I am open to that too. Also, if it is preferred that the input is a of type `numeric` rather than `character` that is acceptable too.

What I have right now is an old fashioned for loop:

```
wsod <- function(str) {
  output <- 0
  for (pos in 1:nchar(str)) {
    digit <- as.numeric(substr(str, pos , pos))
    output <- output + pos * digit
  }
  output
}
```

[A few solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35587998/tips-for-cleaning-up-a-challenges-answer-weighted-sum-of-digits) have been proposed for Python (using a numeric input) but I don't think they apply to R directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> number <-  1059
> x <- strsplit(as.character(number), "")[[1]] 
> y <- seq_len(nchar(number))
> as.numeric(as.numeric(x) %*% y)
[1] 52
```

Comment: I ran a benchmark with 1 million randomly generated integers between 1 and 100,000,000; my for loop took about 20 seconds to do what this approach does in about 5 seconds

Answer (score 2):

```
weighted.digit <- function(str) {
  splitted.nums <- as.numeric(strsplit(str, '')[[1]])
  return(sum(splitted.nums * 1:length(splitted.nums)))
}

weighted.digit('1059')

[1] 52
```

One could modify this to accept a numeric input, and then simply convert that to character as a first step.